# Callback загрузки изображения

Tags: jquery, javascript

Такой вопрос, как получить callback по окончанию загрузки изображения, вот допустим таким методом мы его загрузили в кеш

```
image=new Image; 
image.src="img.png";
```

Так вот как узнать что загрузка завершилась ?

Comment: перед src поставить 

  image.onload=function(){}

Comment: Немного подумал и собрал такую конструкцию
    
    // Вешаем событие
    document.getElementById('load').onclick = function() {
        // Выводим что нибудь пока идет загрузка
 info.innerHTML = 'Loading';
        // Создаем объект Img
 image = new Image;
        // Событие по окончанию загрузки изображения
 image.onload = function() {
    document.body.appendChild(image);
 }
        // Присваиваем путь до загруженной картинки
 image.src =     "http://img11.nnm.me/0/6/3/2/1/223035e6e8fd1e9a435170b23d5.jpg";

Но ходят слухи что в Opera такой метод не работает

Comment: Про onload я знаю, но что там за ошибки, про которые так громко говорят, у меня просто на Linux во всех браузерах работает хорошо

Comment: ну проверьте ещё аттрибут complete сразу после присвоения src

if (image.complete) image.onload.apply(image);

Comment: Я просто не знаю что там за ошибка в этой Opera, поэтому хотел спросить, а что эта проверка даст. Так получается мы проверим загружена ли фотка, а если нет, то получается мы снимем событие onload, так что ли ?

Comment: нет, complete проверить не загрузился ли файл (иногда, если файл уже в кэше onload не вызывается, хотя я если честно не уверен уже что так бывает ), вообще там надо наверное какую-то ещё проверку еще ставить (на всяк случай), но лучше просто найти что там точно с оперой.